# Determining duplicate letter counts between an array of strings

Tags: php

I have an array of strings of random letters, and I need to know which letters are consistent between the array members. The count of the letters are important.

My method right now is loop through the array, doing a split, then looping through the spitted string to count the occurrences of each letter, then update the array with `letter => count`

Then do an array_reduce that creates a new array of members who only occur in all arrays. But, it's not working.

```
<?
$a[] = "emaijuqqrauw";
$a[] = "aaeggimqruuz";
$a[] = "aabimqrtuuzw";
$a[] = "aacikmqruuxz";
$a[] = "aacikmqruuxz";
$a[] = "aaciimqruuxy";

foreach($a as $b){
    $n = str_split($b, 1);
    foreach($n as $z){
        $arr[$z] = substr_count($b, $z);
    }
    ksort($arr);
    $array[] = $arr;
    unset($arr);
}

$n = array_reduce($array, function($result, $item){
    if($result === null){
        return $item;
    }else{
        foreach($item as $key => $val){
            if(isset($result[$key])){
                $new[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        return $new;
    }
});

foreach($n as $key => $val){
    echo str_repeat($key, $val);
}
```

This returns `aaiimqruu` - which is kinda right, but there's only 2 `i`'s in the last element of the array. There's only one `i` in the rest. I'm not sure how to break that down farther and get it to return `aaimqruu`- which I'll then pop into a SQL query to find a matching word, `aquarium`

Comment: I've edited my question to be more specific and I've added some updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `array_reduce` is the best function for what this purpose, however I just didn't think of adding a conditional to give me the desired effect.

```
$new[$key] = ($result[$key] > $val) ? $val : $result[$key];
```

to replace

```
$new[$key] = $val;
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There's [array_intersect()](http://php.net/array_intersect), which is most likely what you'd want. Given your $a array, you'd do something like:

```
$a = array(.... your array...);
$cnt = count($a);
for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
   $a[$i] = explode('', $a[$i]); // split each string into array of letters
}
$common = $a[0]; // save the first element
for($i = 1; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
   $common = array_intersect($common, $a[$i]);
}

var_dump($common);
```

Comment: String cannot be split using Empty delimiter. I just found that out :)

Answer (score 1):

How about you do it this way? Finds out the occurrence of an item throughout the array.

```
function findDuplicate($string, $array) {
   $count = 0;
   foreach($array as $item) {
        $pieces = str_split($item);
        $pcount= array_count_values($pieces);
        if(isset($pcount[$string])) {
           $count += $pcount[$string];
        }
   }
   return $count;
}

echo findDuplicate("a",$a);
```

### Tested :)

> Gives **12**, using your array, which is correct.

---

#### Update

My solution above already had your answer

```
    $pieces = str_split($item);
    $pcount= array_count_values($pieces);
    //$pcount contains, every count like [a] => 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this `findDuplicate`  function returns a count, where I want it to return either a string representing the letters and their count, or an array. (Example: `aaimqruu`or `Array([a] => 2, [i] => 1, [m] => 1, [q] => 1, [r] => 1, [u] => 2)`)